# Show function keys on control strip when using app is not working

Tags: mac, preferences, touch-bar

Adding the app in the systems preferences as followed:

- Go to Apple > System Preferences
- Select the Keyboard preference pane
- Click on the Shortcuts tab In the left sidebar,
- select the Function
  Keys option On the right-hand side
- click on the plus + button Search
  for the app you want to use
- Add the app

[image]

After opening the app `RStudio Version 1.1.383` the touch bar is not switching to the Fn keys.

Of note, it has been worked for a while until I updated the app. I already removed the app, clean installed it, restarted the Mac,... with no success at all.

Comment: Is it just with RStudio that the touch bar is not switching or does it happen with all apps?  Does the touch bar become unresponsive after this?

Comment: No this behavior is just with this app. Other apps can be specified, and the Fn keys are showing up as expected.

Comment: Have you contacted RStudio support?  From how you described it, they might have a bug in their app.

Comment: Do you have RStudio installed twice maybe?

Comment: No I deleted the app using AppCleaner. Thus, there should be removed everything prior the new installation. I will contact them.